# MFC app with managed dll fails on windows XP

Tags: mfc, windows-xp, log4net, unmanaged, managed

I have a MFC application.
I wanted to introduce logging in this application.
I took log4net.dll (managed DLL) and wrapped it with a my C++/CLI LoggerLibrary.dll (unmanaged DLL).

My MFC application links with LoggerLibrary.dll.
My MFC application is compiled 32 bit with platform tool set targeting windows XP.

When running the application on windows 7 32 and 64 all works as expected.

When running the application on windows XP 64 bit - get the following error:
" is not a valid win32 application."

Any ideas on how this may be solved?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 0):

OK - after changing my search criteria, came up with this [C++\CLI applicatin crash on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890796/c-cli-applicatin-crash-on-load).

Works like a charm for me too...